# How do I delete results from a select join statement

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-delete

How do I delete the result from the Select Join statement below.

```
SELECT 
   t2.TransactionID
FROM
    TableA AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    TABLEB AS t2 ON t1.TransactionID = t2.TransactionID
WHERE
    t2.accountingDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' AND '2011-12-30 00:00:00.0000000'
```

Comment: Delete the query result? What do you mean? Do you want to delete all rows from tableA and tableB that appear in your query result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you're asking how to delete the result set from both tables.  Within the context of a SQL statement, you can't.  A sql delete statement only acts on a single table.  You'll have to do 2 deletes, first deleting the 'TableA' record, then the 'TableB' record.

```
delete from tableA where transctionID in
(select transactionID from tableB where accountingDate between ...);

delete from TableB where accountingDate between ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is filter out the result not needed, you can use "Not in" in your select query, for example filter out 'id1' and 'id2' like following:

```
Select t2.TransaationID from TableA as t1 INNER JOION TABLEB as t2 ON t1.TransactionID = t2.TransactionID where t2.accountingDate BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' and ''2011-12-30 00:00:00.0000000 
and t1.TransactionID not in ('id1','id2')
```